# Equivalent Operation to b"" for an already defined string Python

Tags: python

I am able to define a bytes string as follows:

```
string = b"0x340xEF"
```

I want to cast an already made string. Let us call it `string` into a bytes string. How do I perform this? `bytes(string)` is not giving me an equivalent result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode the string to be able to convert it to bytes:

```
string = "b0x340xEF".encode("latin-1")
print(string)
```

**Output:**

```
b'b0x340xEF'
```

Comment: The `bytes` call is superflous; `string` is already a `bytes` object (though its name is then misleading).

Comment: The question simply uses an ASCII string, so using `.encode("us-ascii")` would probably be more correct. For any actually useful example, UTF-8 is almost certainly the wrong encoding.

Comment: @tripleee: Plain `"ascii"` is the standard name (it's optimized to avoid actual codec lookup if you use that name). That said, if you want straight one-to-one mapping from any byte to Unicode characters with equivalent ordinals and back, `"latin-1"` provides that.